# How do I serve a binary data from Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, binary-data

I have a numpy array, that I want to serve using Tornado, but when I try to write it using `self.write(my_np_array)` I just get an AssertionErrror.

What am I doing wrong?

```
File "server.py", line 28, in get
self.write(values)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 468, in write
chunk = utf8(chunk)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 160, in utf8
assert isinstance(value, unicode)
```

Comment: What does the error say? Most likely you need some way to serialise the data (convert it to a series of bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what your goal is, but if you want to get a string representation of the object you can do

```
self.write(str(your_object))
```

If you want to serve the numpy array as a python object in order to use it on a different client you need to pickle the object first

```
import pickle
self.write(pickle.dumps(your_object))
```

the object can then be retrieved with

```
your_object = pickle.loads(sent_object)
```

Keep in mind that it is dangerous to unpickle objects from an untrusted source as it can lead to malicious code execution.

**Edit:**

If you want to transfer a numpy array and use it within javascript you don't need a binary representation.

Just convert the numpy array to a list

```
your_numpy_list = your_numpy_object.tolist()
```

and convert it to json

```
import json
self.write(json.dumps(your_numpy_list))
```

at the javascript side you just parse the result string

```
var result = JSON.parse(resultString)
```

and create the typed array from it

```
var typedResult = new Float32Array(result)
```

voila!

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to read the binary array with a JavaScript TypedArray. I want to transfer a binary numpy array of floats representing a grid of datapoints to a javascript web app.

Comment: in this case I would use json instead of a binary representation. see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. However I need it to be a the binary representation of the numpy array. The array will be very big (millions of float64s).